# How do I redirect a subdomain to another internal webserver without affecting the RDP Gateway

Tags: iis, redirect, web

we have a standard windows server 2022 running IIS 10 and remote desktop gateway.
we use rdp.domain.com for the gateway address for external RDP Users.

we would like to run another internal windows server with IIS 10 for a wedbased app for external users at app.domain.com

what would be the best solution to allow users to access the new app webserver externally.

have tried IIS Rewrite but just cant get it to work. it either redirects all traffic including RDP or will not redirect to new webserver.

the app webserver works fine for onpresmise users.

Comment: I'm confused, how is RDP at all effected by IIS Rewrite? IIS deals with web traffic, port 80 and or 443. RDP is (by default) on port 3389 (IIRC)

Comment: Use a different public ip address for the new web app. Set up the appropriate port forwarding/NAT on the firewall for the internal host of this web app.

Comment: @JaromandaX Connections to Remote Desktop Gateway are normally handled via RPC over HTTP, not a direct RDP connection, so yes ports 80 and 443 are used for RDP.

Comment: ahh, forgot about the gateway that was not mentioned at all in the OP :p

Comment: ARR is needed to build a full feature reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing